# How to translate image points position(row, column) to their coordinate(x,y)?

Tags: plotting, image

Here is the code to find image edge and record the morphological connected pixels positions. How to translate the row/col positions to x/y coordinates?

```
i = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
im = EdgeDetect[i, 5];
imm = MorphologicalComponents[im];
a = Position[imm,200];
```

"a" gives a list of positions, how to translate them to x/y coordinates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The image coordinate `x` is the second element of the position; the image coordinate `y` is the first position subtracted from the number of rows plus 1.

```
rows = First@ImageDimensions[i];
xy1 = AffineTransform[{{{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}, {0, rows + 1}}][a]
```

Another way is to use [`PixelValuePositions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PixelValuePositions.html) on the morphological components, converted to an `Image`:

```
xy2 = PixelValuePositions[Image[imm], 200]
```

Check:

```
xy1 == xy2
(* True *)
```

(They happen to be in the same order.)